# how to retrieve author's name from Wikipedia API?

Tags: javascript, json, api, wikipedia-api

I'm getting a JSON with all the text but what I need is just the key info for this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit  (author's name, type of site, logo of the publication, etc.)   Can I add any props to this string? https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=Reddit&callback=?

Comment: Define who is the author of an article on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will use **Query** instead of parse and you will send the parameter in **prop**

For example https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Reddit&prop=contributors

Reference : https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties

Comment: Note also that because there are more authors than the number that are returned with the first query, you will need to make several queries and use the [continue parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries).